# Magento: how to disable prototype.js on frontend only?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I'm looking for a simple way to disable prototype.js on the Magento frontend only (and continue loading it on the admin side). I'm working on a custom design and pretty much exclusively using jQuery for the frontend. I'm trying to troubleshoot some javascript errors and it would be useful if I could just not load prototype.js at all on the front end, but I still need it for the admin side.

I'm able to accomplish a workaround by modifying my head.phtml, and replacing

```
echo $this->getCssJsHtml()
```

with the output from that function, minus the line for prototype. I realize this is probably not going to be the ideal way to do it, but I'm not too familiar with all of the Magento XML configuration. What is the best way to disable prototype in Magento for the frontend only?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `prototype.js` and `jQuery` simultaneously in fronted, for this you need to make little changes in `jQuery` syntax, Use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

**Eg :-**

**Normal jQuery :**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

**In Magento :**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "well Done :-)!" );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the prototype.js from frontend from any CMS page, you can change the layout file like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_page>
    <reference name="root">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/prototype.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
</layout>
```